# Gatsby build output without version

Tags: npm, gatsby, netlify

I have a Gatsby site that has several SASS files that are built into single file using `gatsby-plugin-sass`

When published (built) using `gatsby build`, site output includes css file with sort of stamp or built number like this:

`/styles.10cd9877d9cd984ac64c.css`

I need to create also a copy without this `stamp` :

`/styles.css`

Can you please give me a hint how to do this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it solved with:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build && cp public/styles.*.css public/styles.css",
```